# Rsync - GVFS - Questions

Tags: rsync, gvfs

I've noticed some issues with rsync and .gvfs over the years. Typically I just `--exclude=.gvfs` in my rsync command and call it a day.

Recently I decided to read the rsync man page top to bottom left to right. After all, what better way to learn? Man pages are quicker than Googling, if you ask me. I had noticed the `-x` flag, which was cited to not cross other file systems. I began to wonder what exactly that meant and thought... would `-x` also ignore `.gvfs`, being a virtual file system?

That said, would:

```
rsync -a --exclude=.gvfs /home/jason /media/externalhdd
```

(be kind of the same as)

```
rsync -ax /home/jason /media/externalhdd
```

????

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be the same.

To check for sure: run `stat` on your two directories: `/home/jason` and `/home/jason/.gvfs`. The `stat` output will show a "device" entry:

```
[jk@pecola ~]$ stat $HOME
  File: `/home/jk'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 803h/2051d  Inode: 5242881     Links: 65
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/      jk)   Gid: ( 1000/      jk)
Access: 2012-03-19 11:53:31.209584100 +0800
Modify: 2012-03-19 11:50:42.941630852 +0800
Change: 2012-03-19 11:50:42.941630852 +0800
 Birth: -
```

-- it's the first item in the third line. The number is shown twice: in hex ('h' suffix), and in decimal ('d' suffix).

If these numbers are different between the two directories, they're considered to be on different device, so the `-x` option will prevent rsync from traversing to this directory.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll likely just leave the --exclude tag in there, but I was curious if -x by nature handled the very task I was accomplishing with --exclude=.gvfs. Now help me out here. I'm trying to understand what happens when you rsync .gvfs. Last I looked, in .gvfs were the contents of my backup server. Yet, I'm rsyncing to my backup server. So, rsyncing .gvfs to my backup server was duplicating my data, because I had my data there already, as well as in .gvfs that was synced. Am I correct in saying that it essentially duplicated, albeit in different locations on the backup server?

Comment: That's correct; by rsyncing the contents of .gvfs, you're copying stuff that's already on the backup server to the backup server. Next time, you'll be copying the same stuff *again*, so you end up with three copies of the data, ad infinitum.

Comment: Keep in mind that `-x` may be more reliable that `--exclude=.gvfs`, as the directory may move - my machine (a precise install) has it in `~/.cache/gvfs`.

Comment: Jeremy, thank you very much for clarifying this. What baffles me more is if this is the case, why is it in 99% of the cases when I hear other users talk about how to set up rsync that they don't include -x. More often than not, it's -azn at most. I think I'll be editing my scripts tonight to rsync -axn and call it a day.

Comment: My apologies, I was typing a bit too carelessly. More times than not I'm seeing simply -av, not -azn. To summarize, if it's this easy to duplicate data, why aren't more examples to helping users out -avx instead of just -av?

Comment: Cancel that. The -x flag will not detect .gvfs as being a different file system. One of the rsync devs just confirmed it, along with a quick bench test I did here on my desktop. In order to avoid .gvfs, --exclude tag must be used. At any rate, still dead simple, but good to be aware of. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: "should"........

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test on Ubuntu 18.04 and `-x` does not exclude `.gvfs`.

Comment: the question: >would -x also ignore .gvfs, being a virtual file system?

Comment: Indeed, that was my mistake.